# How to get data from data class in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

im relatively new to AS and want to implement a LogIn System using Room for my local db.
The following Query takes the values for name and password and checks if this user exists in the db.

```
@Query("SELECT userName, password FROM users_data WHERE userName LIKE :name_input AND password LIKE :pw_input")
fun findUser(name_input : String, pw_input : String): List<LogIn>
```

The data should be returned to the LogIn() POJO:

```
package com.example.app.data

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey


@Entity(tableName = "users_data")
data class user(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  val id : Int, val mail : String, val userName : String, val password : String)

data class LogIn(
  @ColumnInfo(name = "userName") val userName: String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "password") val password: String
)
```

To figure out if the entered user exist, I want to check the data of LogIn() and work with it.
Unfortunately I do not know an efficient way to do so yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying todo is returning user data from user_table
But what you are doing is returning data from wrong table
Try returning `List<user>` not `List<Login>`(and refactor according if necessary)

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Nasir Aziz, thanks for your response. The user data is safed in the user data class, but I created the LogIn data class, because I just need the username and the password for the LogIn process. Nevertheless return the data from the "user_table" in the Query above. Can you please specify what you mean by that and "Try returning List not List"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: extremely sorry for typos, i have edited the answer, sorry. and how about to take data from login screen and check if the data entered matches in database with `if exists` query of SQL

Comment: now I got you, thanks for your response. I have 3 questions specified to your answer. Since I just want the username and password, I actually do not need the user class do I? The LogIn class also exist in the users_data Entity and thus is able to search in the db, or am I wrong? Also I think „if exist“ calls are not possible when using Room for the local db. I really don‘t know how to handle this the best way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: well yes you can use users_data which have LogIn class to search in db. and yes you can use if exists in local db i have used it when i wanted to check if a Movie exists in users db or not and update UI accordingly. and well im new to android too but this type of thing i have done couple of time so i felt i could help. hope it is to some level.